# Maximum and minimum values over a triangle

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-theorem

I was triying to find maximum and mnimum values of $f(x,y)=xy(1-x-y)$ over the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. I have seen that vertices give minimum for this function. When I use first partial derivatives to find critical points, I have found that $(1/3,1/3)$ is the point which gives maximum value over this triangle. However, I confused about why Extreme Value Theorem does not work here. Due to theorem, maximum and minimum must occur on boundary but $(1/3,1/3)$ is an interior point. I didn't understand what is the reason of this.

Thanks in advance for any comment or answer.

Comment: Global maximum, minimum are at a critical point or on the boundary.

Comment: @user376343 thanks a lot

Comment: I dont see what the Extreme value theorem has got to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maximum/minimum can occur in stationary points in the interior of the domain, in the boundary, or in points where $f$ is not differentiable. In this case, they will occur in the boundary or in the critical point that you mentioned. The function will attain a maximum on $(1/3,1/3)$ and a minimum all over the boundary($f=0$ on the boundary).

Comment: (+1) but IMO critical points include points of non-differentiability.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You are right, I meant stationary points, I'll edit.